# How do I link an action to a button without creating a route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a vote button in my Rails app and to allow a user to vote I've created a route that connects the button and the respective action.

Route:

```
/posts/1/vote_up
```

But on other ROR websites I've been analyzing they can accomplish the same thing without creating a route (or at least, without showing it to the public user). An example would be [Producthunt](http://www.producthunt.com), there's a vote button, but when you hover over it, there is no route or URL mapped to it.

How does one do that? Can I link an action to a button without creating a route to it?

Comment: A route is always required to access an action. The way sites like Producthunt hide the url is they us javascript to send request to the server.

Comment: @Nitish So how do you use JS to send a request?

Comment: **AJAX**. If you are using jQuery, you can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make a request to the server.

Comment: Awesome! How about the js-routes gem?

Comment: Haven't used it yet, but from it's documentation it seems that the gem makes rails routes available in JS. You will still need to use something like jQuery.ajax() to actually make the requests.

Comment: Oh great :/ Is there a tutorial or something for using jQuery.ajax()?

Comment: Personally, I haven't used any tutorial, but [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+ajax+with+rails&oq=jquery+ajax+with+rails) should get you started

Comment: It can be done using ajax call through your view, it does not require routes for this voting, otherwise you need to do this using via action.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your controller or models this is how you would do it.  This is a silent Ajax call.

```
<%= form_tag(post, id: "post" + String(post.id),method: :patch, remote: true, authenticity_token: true) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "post[voter]", current_user.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "post[vote_up]", true %>
  <%= button_tag "Up Vote", onclick: "$('#post#{String(post.id)}').trigger('submit.rails');" %>
<% end %>
```

The `method: :patch` will call your **update** method from your controller.  So now you don't need to define a route.

If you're doing an increment in your DB you'll need to add the logic in your update method of your controller to catch the param, delete it, and then increase your count.  You may also want to implement a way that the current user can only vote once per post.

In your controller you could add a JavaScript response of nothing if you'd like `format.js {render nothing: true}`

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.js {render nothing: true}
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
    else
      format.js {render nothing: true}
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

---

### In response to:

> If I just need a 'link_to' to call a function in the controller with silent AJAX (instead of a form_tag doing that, like in your example), how would I achieve it?

A link by itself will not send any data... which is why you had to define a route. Unless you give the link params.

```
<%= link_to "Up Vote", post_path(@post, post: {up_vote: true}) %>
```

You can also provide a method for this.  So if you put `method: :patch` it should call your update method.

```
<%= link_to "Up Vote", post_path(@post, post: {up_vote: true}), method: :patch %>
```

These examples will add a bunch of text in the url in the form of params:

```
# posts/1?post[up_vote]=true
```

So this works without configuring your `routes.rb` file.  But you may need to add more params and modify your controller to handle these params.

---

### My answer:

What I've written here will not appear as a form, but look just like a button.  You can substitute `button_tag` with anything else that supports `onclick` to submit the data you want to the server.

Instead of a hyperlink reference you use hidden fields of a form to pass the data you want to use.  You can't actually use link_to without giving it a hpyerlink reference.  So a substitute for that is `content_tag 'a'`.  Just replace the previous form `button_tag` line to produce this.

```
<%= form_tag(post, id: "post" + String(post.id),method: :patch, remote: true, authenticity_token: true) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "post[voter]", current_user.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "post[vote_up]", true %>
  <%= content_tag 'a', "Up Vote", onclick: "$('#post#{String(post.id)}').trigger('submit.rails');" , style: 'cursor: pointer' %>
<% end %>
```

It now appears you have a regular link, and the mouse will change when you click on it.  Now the issue is it will look like nothing happens when people click on the "Up Vote" link.  You will need to add a CSS and/or JS action to change the user's view once they click on the link.  So as well as the `onlcick` performing a submit you need to call a Javascript method to modify your content from "Up Vote" to "Thanks for Voting!".  Other then that this works, it doesn't "appear" to be a form, and you have your link.

If you for some reason do want the page to reload after the link has been clicked you can change the JS response.

```
format.js { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Thanks for voting!' }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! If I just need a 'link_to' to call a function in the controller with silent AJAX (instead of a form_tag doing that, like in your example), how would I achieve it? I understand that i would need a :remote => true and a respective JS to make the changes in the view. But the problem I'm facing is that I still need a route defined to achieve this, which makes the URL scheme visible to the public. Could I bypass that with AJAX/UJS?

Comment: I've extended my answer.  The user will not see that there is a form either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is what we used to use before named routes:

```
link_to "Link to listing new", controller: :listings, action: :new
#or
link_to "string method", "/listings/new"
```